How can i add an Integer and a Number in an EditText and then rewrite the EditText with the new Integer?
I want to add the number written in "Zahl 1" and add it with the number in EditText (in this example it is 1500). Then i want to rewrite the number in EditText to the new number.
I thought the process was pretty simple and obvious but when i run the program and hit the add Button, the app crashes.
You can ignore the EditText "zahl2" for now. It is not important to my problem.
So here is the code:
package com.example.rechnen_speichern;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    Button save, addieren;
    EditText zahl1, zahl2;
    TextView ergebnis;
    String finalergebnis;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        save = findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        addieren = findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        zahl1 = findViewById(R.id.eingabe1);
        zahl2 = findViewById(R.id.eingabe2);
        ergebnis = findViewById(R.id.ergebnis);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("myergebnis", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sp.edit();

        String data = sp.getString("key", "");
        ergebnis.setText(data);


        addieren.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                int z1 = Integer.parseInt(zahl1.getText().toString());
                int z4 = Integer.parseInt(zahl2.getText().toString());
                int z2 = Integer.parseInt(ergebnis.getText().toString());


                int z3 = z1 + z2; //add zahl1 + ergebnis -> then overwrite ergebnis with the new number z3

                ergebnis.setText(String.valueOf(z3));

            }
        });


        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


            finalergebnis = ergebnis.getText().toString();

            editor.putString("key", finalergebnis);
            editor.apply();


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });

    }
}

Here the xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ergebnis"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
       />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/eingabe1"
        android:hint="Zahl 1"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/eingabe2"
        android:hint="Zahl 2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:text="Addieren"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/btnsave"
        android:text="Save"/>

</LinearLayout>

So i tried the obvious. I set up 3 Integers: z1(the number you add), z2 (the given number), z3 (the sum of z1+z2).
After that i set the EditText to z3. View of App
So in this case z1 (500) + z2 (1500) = z3 (2000)
After i press the add button the EditText should display 2000.

The issue causing the app to crash likely lies in the part of your code where you attempt to parse the value of ergebnis (the TextView that displays the result) to an integer. When the app first runs, ergebnis might not contain a valid integer, which would cause a NumberFormatException when you attempt to parse it. Let's modify the code to handle this potential issue.
Here's an updated version of your MainActivity class with additional checks to prevent crashes:
Java:

package com.example.rechnen_speichern;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.EdgeToEdge;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.graphics.Insets;
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat;
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button save, addieren;
    EditText zahl1, zahl2;
    TextView ergebnis;
    String finalergebnis;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        EdgeToEdge.enable(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main), (v, insets) -> {
            Insets systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom);
            return insets;
        });

        save = findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        addieren = findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        zahl1 = findViewById(R.id.eingabe1);
        zahl2 = findViewById(R.id.eingabe2);
        ergebnis = findViewById(R.id.ergebnis);

        sp = getSharedPreferences("myergebnis", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sp.edit();

        String data = sp.getString("key", "0"); // default to "0" if no value is stored
        ergebnis.setText(data);

        addieren.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    int z1 = Integer.parseInt(zahl1.getText().toString());
                    int z2 = Integer.parseInt(ergebnis.getText().toString()); // This should now default to 0 initially

                    int z3 = z1 + z2; // add zahl1 + ergebnis -> then overwrite ergebnis with the new number z3

                    ergebnis.setText(String.valueOf(z3));
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter valid numbers.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalergebnis = ergebnis.getText().toString();
                editor.putString("key", finalergebnis);
                editor.apply();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}

I hope I have been helpful!!

Wow, thank you very much! It works perfect, although i do not understand why. I am really new to this! But i will study your code :)

@Dave1209 Welcome to this site, seems like you got the solution consider reading this and if  Maya's solution works for you then you can accept it by clicking on tick mark on the left side of answer. put some efforts learning how stackoverflow works by taking the tour.

String data = sp.getString("key", "");
        ergebnis.setText(data);

comment the two lines and then try again
also change this code like this
 string value1 = zahl1.getText().toString()
 int z1 = Integer.parseInt(value1);
 int z4 = Integer.parseInt(zahl2.getText().toString());
 int z2 = Integer.parseInt(ergebnis.getText().toString());

I think problem is with Integer.parseInt conversion string to int
take a look at the conversion your problem is solved

Thank´s but this did not work for me!
